# Generate 7 random letters into 7 form fields

Tags: javascript

I am in need to generate 1 random letter into 7 form fields. An example of the fields would look like below.

The letters can repeat, but only based on the letter and an amount of times that letter can repeat

For instance

- a x 7 (a can repeat only 7 times)
- b x 5 (b can repeat only 5 times)
- c x 2 (c can repeat only 2 times)

and so on

```
<input type="text" name="1" maxlength="1" />
<input type="text" name="2" maxlength="1" />
<input type="text" name="3" maxlength="1" />
<input type="text" name="4" maxlength="1" />
<input type="text" name="5" maxlength="1" />
<input type="text" name="6" maxlength="1" />
<input type="text" name="7" maxlength="1" />
```

So far I have

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function randomString() {
var chars = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXTZ";
var string_length = 1;
var randomstring = '';
for (var i=0; i<string_length; i++) {
    var rnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length);
    randomstring += chars.substring(rnum,rnum+1);
}
document.randform.randomfield.value = randomstring;
}
</script>
```

Im a little lost because this will only place it in one field. I am not sure how to optimize my javascript so that it can generate all the letters (1 into each field) AND make sure the letters dont repeat beyond what they are allowed too.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why don't you just generate an array comprising of 7 a's, 5 b's and 2 c's ... then shuffle the array (fisher yates) and pick the values out one by one.

Answer (score 0):

`document.randform.randomfield.value = randomstring;`

randomfield is not specified in the block you give.  I suspect that either it's interpreted as `0`, in which case you might get the first field.  Or you might initialize it to a particular field in a section of code you didn't provide.  Or (most likely, from my limited knowledge of JavaScript) it's really the name of a field that isn't shown in your HTML snippet.

Regardless, this is likely where your error is.  You need to change the location where you want to save the value if you want to save the value to multiple locations.